# Send data to node.js from Angular2 Component

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

So i wanna send some `string` value to my node server and find that value in MySQL table.

I have a component which is getting data from service

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.instructionsService.getAllInstructions().subscribe(instructions => {
      this.instructions = instructions;
    });
}
```

Then i have a service which is fetching data from `node` server

```
getAllInstructions() {
    return this.http.get('/api/profile/')
      .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And finally i have node api

```
app.get('/profile',getAllInstructions);
function getAllInstructions(req,res){
connection.query("select * from users where id='somekindofid'",function(err, rows, fields) {
        res.json(rows);
    }
}
```

`

And i wanna replace that *'somekindofid'* by the value ill be sending from my component

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing `id` to node method inside its URL itself. 
For the same you should change API route to `/profile/:id` where `id` is parameter that will be passed from consumer of the API.

**Node**

```
app.get('/profile/:id',getAllInstructions);
function getAllInstructions(req,res){
   connection.query("select * from users where id="+ req.params.id,function(err, rows, fields) {
        res.json(rows);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
getAllInstructions(id) {
    return this.http.get(`/api/profile/${id}`)
      .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    let userId = 'pankaj';
    this.instructionsService.getAllInstructions(userId).subscribe(instructions => {
      this.instructions = instructions;
    });
}
```